# single-spa root-config as angular project

Tags: angular, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I am trying to tear down our monolithic angular application to single-spa  micro fronts ends.

I would like to keep core authentication and authorization modules at root-config so I can pass user info to individual modules.

So I am looking for any existing or sample GitHub projects where I can refer for angular single spa root-configs

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The single-spa team recommends *not* trying to put the root config into an application for better separation of concerns. See also ["Should I have a parent/root app and children apps"](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/faq/#should-i-have-a-parentroot-app-and-children-apps) and ["Architectural overview"](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/getting-started-overview#architectural-overview). Instead, you should have an independent root-config and your first single-spa application should be the monolith.

However, there are [community examples](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/examples/#community-examples) that may have some basic guidance for what you want to achieve. Just note that the core team does not provide support for those examples since they're community contributions.